# Database Table Design

Tags: database-design

I want to know you opinion and what should be the best approach for this case:

I have 2 table called:
- clients;
- suppliers;

I've create 2 pages for people to leave feedback about a client and for a supplier.  With that in mind a created a table feedbacks.

Now the question is which approach should I choose:

1) Create one table called feedbacks with 2 foreign keys (clientid and supplierid).  With this approach if they leave a feedback to the client then the FK supplierid would be empty.

2) create 2 tables called clientfeedbacks and suppliersfeedback.  With this approach since each table would only have one FK then no FK would be empty.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have one table called feedback, and then two separate join tables: client_feedback that maps client_id to feedback_id and then supplier_feedback that amps supplier_id to feedback_id?  (has_many through  in rails speak)

Comment: +1: great alternative that is will actually be more descriptive from the data structure than trying to differentiate two data tables or two columns.

Comment: never thought of that...I like it

Answer (score 0):

By far option #2 is better between the two choices you gave.